# jQuery Dialog Scroll to bottom?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, scroll

It seems like this question has been answered a few times before, but I simply cannot get anything to work for me. I have a jQuery dialog popup that loads information and I'd like for the dialog to automatically scroll to the bottom of the form once it's loaded. I attempted to use the jQuery scrollTop: attribute, but it attempted to scroll before all the content was loaded so it didn't end up being at the end of the page once the popup was fully loaded. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
function viewdialog(dialogid,docname) {
    var state = true;
    var ev;
    $(dialogid).dialog( {
        title: "Some Title" + docname,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        position: dialogposition,
        show: {
        effect: "slide",
        duration: 500
            },
        hide: {
        effect: "puff",
        duration: 500
            },
        buttons: {

        Resize: function(){

                if (state) {
                     $(dialogid).effect( "size", { to: { width: 1000,height: 800 },scale:"box"  } );}
                else {  $(dialogid).effect( "size", { to: { width: 800,height: 600 },scale:"box" });}
                state = !state;
                },
        Close: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                } 
            }

   });
    $(dialogid).dialog("open");

}
```

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: That's helpful, isn't it? I've added the code. I tried to instruct it to call a function on 'open:', but the function calls before all the content is loaded so no scrolling occurs. :(